# Coin slider not working on ASP.net server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webserver, slider

I'm making a website for a company and I would like to use a Jquery slider on the Home page. I'm using Visual Studio to make the website and I'm trying to implement the Coin slider to the page. I downloaded the files for it and copied the code, changed the pictures and everything is going fine when I try to see it on my localhost. But the problem is that when I upload it to the server than the slider is not working at all, it just puts the pictures under each other.
The code that I'm using is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Jquery/coin-slider.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/coin-slider-styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

And:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#coin-slider').coinslider({ width: 759, navigation: true, delay: 5000,effect: 'straight', });
 });
</script>
```

And for the images:

```
<div id="coin-slider">

     <img src="Images/image1.jpg" alt="" width="759px" height="256px" />
     <img src="Images/image2.jpg" alt="" width="759px" height="256px" />
     <img src="Images/image3.jpg" alt="" width="759px" height="256px" />

</div>
```

If I try to see the problem with Firefox's Web Console then I get the following message:

```
 TypeError: $("#coin-slider").coinslider is not a function
```

I don't know what is going wrong when I upload it to the server so I would appreciate any help. :) I also tried using Nivo slider instead of Coin slider to see if the problem was with the slider but everything was the same - it worked on my localhost but not on the server.

Here is the link where you can see the website as it is right now:
http://web.bptech.dk:33001/

Thank you for any help!! :)

Comment: Probably the `/Jquery/coin-slider.min.js` is not found, and now I see that ether the .css is found - permission is denied. Check it by your self http://web.bptech.dk:33001/Jquery/coin-slider.min.js

Comment: Could that be the problem that I don't have permission to change something on the server? Could the problem be because of the server?

Comment: Ether is a problem on the server, ether the files not exists at all. How do you have copy the rest files ? Maybe you have set other settings that not permit the css and the js to be readed.

Comment: I checked the files and they exist so there should be no problem with them. I'm guessing the problem might be on the server because I have other css file for styling the layout of the website and it works fine. Is there something I can do if the problem is on the server?

Comment: Get with your ftp client and check/change the permission on this files

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a pathing issue, "/", will probably not be the same path on both machines.